# Best way to remove a "column" from a collection using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I'd like to remove one or more "columns" from a collection (array of objects) in JavaScript using Lodash.

For example, in the following collection:

```
var users = [
  { 'name': 'barney', 'age': 36, 'alum': true },
  { 'name': 'fred',   'age': 40, 'alum': false }
];
```

...I may want to remove all columns that start with the letter A, or something similar.

I know that I can achieve something similar on a per-object basis using the `_.omit()` method, but this does not seem to stick if I do it in an `each` loop.

What is the best way to go about this using Lodash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that I can achieve something similar on a per-object basis using the `_.omit()` method, but this does not seem to stick if I do it in an `each` loop.

Because `omit` returns a new object, and `each` does nothing to the array.

You want to use `map` to get a new array with the new objects:

```
users = _.map(users, function(user) {
    return _.omit(user, function(value, key) {
        return key.charAt(0) == "a";
    });
});
```